# Kentico 6 - Scheduled Task

Tags: asp.net-mvc, scheduled-tasks, kentico

I've migrated a Kentico 6 site from one to another and the Scheduled Tasks have stopped running.

On the old site, there isn't a windows service running, but there is the web.config param :

```
<add key="CMSUseAutomaticScheduler" value="true" />
```

So i'm a little confused to why it's not working on the new server. For each of the scheduled tasks, it is set to use an external server (which according to their documentation is the windows service, which isn't installed - helpful!)

Anyone have any ideas?

Regards,

Answer (score 1):

There are basically 2 options:

1. Either to turn off the automatic scheduling (then the request-based scheduler will take place). `<add key="CMSUseAutomaticScheduler" value="true" />`
2. Or you can install the missing windows services. You can use Kentico Service Manager utility or do it via command line. Both approaches are described in the [documentation](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K82/Installing+the+Scheduler+Windows+service).

I also strongly recommend reading [this article](https://docs.kentico.com/display/K82/Configuring+scheduled+task+execution) to know the difference between the two. And to be aware of possible drawbacks of request-based scheduling.